# UITextView font is nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, fonts, uitextview, uifont

I created a UITextView with a font size of 14 in a storyboard and hooked it up to the detailDescriptionLabel property of my ViewController. This code is in viewDidLoad:

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];
NSLog(@"text is %@; font is %@", self.detailDescriptionLabel.text, self.detailDescriptionLabel.font);
```

The console output follows:

```
text is Lorem Ipsum; font is (null)
```

Why is the font set to nil? The setFont: is working; the font does shrink. I want to get the font so after a gesture I can call lineHeight on the font. This way, I can find out which line has been tapped with the following code:

```
int line = [tap locationInView:tap.view].y / self.detailDescriptionLabel.font.lineHeight;
```

Here, too, the font is nil. line is set to -2147483648, which is obviously not what I want.

Comment: Have you tried just setting the font in the storyboard?

Comment: I have used your code and everything works fine!

Answer (score 115):

Try checking the "selectable" checkbox for this `UITextView` in Interface Builder. It's in the Attributes Inspector. Per @VahramDodoryan's comment below, you can then set `selectable` to false if you don't want to support selection.

I can't explain why this works, but it's probably a UIKit bug. I had an `IBOutlet` to a `UITextView` whose font property was nil, and it would not respond to any font or text-color changes in code until *after* its text property had been set. I arrived at this solution through trial-and-error.

---

If you're still encountering this issue on recent releases of iOS, consider opening a radar:

- https://openradar.appspot.com/15854592
- https://openradar.appspot.com/15196932

Comment: I don't know why this is required (on iOS7), but it worked for me as well.  Once I set the "selectable" box in IB I could query the textField for the font.  Text being set to the textField in iOS7 was not adopting the font so I query the field, set the text, and reset the font, which makes it work.

Comment: Thank you for narrowing this down!  I was about to ditch storyboards because I need the font to calculate the size of the view.

Comment: It sounds crazy, but checking Selectable also fixed my issue.

Comment: this definitely should be marked as answer. thanks a lot Ty Cobb!

Comment: You can set textView.selectable = NO property in code to make it non-selectable without this weird issue.

Comment: Is there any perceivable reason why Apple have set it up like this? Or should this be filed as a bug with Apple?

Comment: FWIW, Same situation in iOS9. Checking 'selectable' on the UITextView let getFont return the font rather than nil.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea why textfield is behaving like this?

Comment: Still same situation in iOS9. Checking 'selectable' on the UITextView let getFont return the font ...

Comment: Same for iOS 10 also. Its awkward since a selectable UITextField can often have a weird impact on rendering performance, so I manually have to re-apply a font after making the view selectable.

Comment: I didnt experience this bug in iOS 10. only in iOS 9 for the textview.

Comment: Disputing hasan83's assertion that the bug is not present in iOS 10.  I am seeing it as well.

Comment: I had this issue in iOS 11 and this fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing every property and constraint , I had on my text view.

Including selectable as suggested above

In frustration in the end I deleted and re-added it and that was the unsatisfying fix.

Answer (score -1):

You should try logging `self.detailDescriptionLabel`. The value might be null.